# social authentication with firebase in VUE3 + Pinia

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, vuejs3, pinia

Wanting to add social authentication to my vue application. How can i add social login such as google authentication within my user pinia store. I have got sign in and register with email and password working but not sure on how to add social authentication (Google login/register & Apple login/register). My action user.js pinia store code is below. Help is appreciated.

```
export const useUserStore = defineStore("user", {
   state: () => ({
       userData: {},
       loadingUser: false,
       loading: false,
   }),
   actions: {
       currentUser() {
           return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
               const unsubcribe = onAuthStateChanged(
                   auth,
                   (user) => {
                       if (user) {
                           this.userData = {
                               email: user.email,
                               uid: user.uid,
                           };
                       }
                       resolve(user);
                   },
                   (e) => reject(e)
               );
               unsubcribe();
           });
       },
       async registerUser(email, password) {
           this.loadingUser = true;
           try {
               const { user } = await createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
                   auth,
                   email,
                   password
               );
               this.userData = { email: user.email, uid: user.uid };
               router.push("/");
           } catch (error) {
               console.log(error);
               this.userData = {};
           } finally {
               this.loadingUser = false;
           }
       },
       async loginUser(email, password) {
           this.loadingUser = true;
           try {
               const { user } = await signInWithEmailAndPassword(
                   auth,
                   email,
                   password
               );
               this.userData = { email: user.email, uid: user.uid };
               router.push("/");
           } catch (error) {
               console.log(error);
               this.userData = {};
           } finally {
               this.loadingUser = false;
           }
       },
           async signOutUser() {
           this.loading = true;
           try {
               await signOut(auth);
           } catch (error) {
               console.log(error);
           } finally {
               this.userData = {};
               this.loading = false;
               router.replace("/authentication");
           }
       },
        async googleSignIn() {
           this.loadingUser = true;
           try {
             const provider = new GoogleAuthProvider();
             const result = await signInWithPopup(auth, provider)
             const credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credentialFromResult(result);
             const token = credential.accessToken;
             console.log(credential)
             this.userData = {};
             
           } catch (error) {
             console.log(error)
             this.userData = {};
           }
            finally {
            this.loadingUser = false;
            router.push("/");
           }
         }
   }
});
```

Comment: Did you see the documentation on [signing on to Firebase Authentication with Google](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/google-signin)?

Comment: i did! but since I'm quite new to vuejs and firebase, i dont really understand. I was following a program course which led me to the above code.

Comment: The course apparently uses email+password sign-in, while you want to sign in with Google. Without seeing what you tried based on the documentation on signing in with Google that I linked, it's going to be hard for us to explain anything better than that documentation does.

Comment: thanks, ive gone through the docs again and came up with the edited code (under the SignOutUser function) . Seems to work. Does that look right to you? once again, I'm new to this so this is definitely a learning experience. Appreciate any help.

Comment: Good to hear you got it working @chisjarn